# Nested fetch() functions with conditional if statement in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, fetch-api

I have a function that runs a `fetch()` and at the very end of the fetch call it logs to the console.

I want to *conditionally* add a second fetch function before the end of the first. It also logs to the console.

I'm having trouble working out how to ensure the first log waits for the second fetch to complete and log its data before actually logging (whether or not it actually needs to run). I've been able to do this with several `else` statements, but I'd like to avoid the repetition.

Codepen @ https://codepen.io/cfxd/pen/bGKmRZj

```js
function alwaysRuns() {
  fetch('https://api.spacexdata.com/v4/launches/latest')
    .then(result => result.json())
    .then(resultJson => {
      const rocketId = resultJson.rocket;
      const rocketName = resultJson.name;
      if(rocketName.includes('Crew')) {
        fetch(`https://api.spacexdata.com/v4/rockets/${rocketId}`)
          .then(rocketResponse => rocketResponse.json())
          .then(rocketJson => {
            console.log('This fetch might not happen, depending on the conditional')
        });
      }
      console.log('this should always log last whether the conditional causes the second fetch to run or not!');
  });
}
alwaysRuns();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `await`

```
function alwaysRuns() {
  fetch('https://api.spacexdata.com/v4/launches/latest')
    .then(result => result.json())
    .then(async resultJson => {
      const rocketId = resultJson.rocket;
      const rocketName = resultJson.name;
      if(rocketName.includes('Crew')) {
        await fetch(`https://api.spacexdata.com/v4/rockets/${rocketId}`)
          .then(rocketResponse => rocketResponse.json())
          .then(rocketJson => {
            console.log('This fetch might not happen, depending on the conditional')
        });
      }
      console.log('this should always log last whether the conditional causes the second fetch to run or not!');
  });
}
alwaysRuns();
```

or even better

```
function alwaysRuns() {
  fetch('https://api.spacexdata.com/v4/launches/latest')
    .then(result => result.json())
    .then(resultJson => {
      const rocketId = resultJson.rocket;
      const rocketName = resultJson.name;
      if(rocketName.includes('Crew')) {
        return fetch(`https://api.spacexdata.com/v4/rockets/${rocketId}`)
          .then(rocketResponse => rocketResponse.json())
          .then(rocketJson => {
            console.log('This fetch might not happen, depending on the conditional')
        });
      }
    }).then(() => {
    console.log('this should always log last whether the conditional causes the second fetch to run or not!');
  });
}
alwaysRuns();
```

Comment: Why is the second one even better?

Comment: Because mixing `then` and `await` is kind of an antipattern